# Typing issue in Outlook 2016 Standard

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

This issue occurs in Outlook 2016 Standard on Windows 10 Pro (fully updated). We first saw this in Outlook but it also occurs in Word. When typing, the cursor will start to jump into the middle of the letter. It's very annoying.

So far we have tried repairing Office, disabling add ins, Windows updates, Auto correction settings. It also happens when running Outlook in safe mode. The screenshot from Outlook shows the behavior. Looking for ideas on how to stop this.

[image: Screenshot of Issue]

Comment: Does this occur in [Clean Boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) mode?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes it does occur in clean boot. It almost seems like some auto correct thing but there are so many options and I don't see any way to disable all auto correct?

Comment: This behavior is not a feature of Office.

Comment: Try disabling hardware graphics acceleration in Outlook under File > Options > Advanced > Display. Also try updating your video driver to see whether it helps.